# How to create bindings for Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, binding, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an iOS static library(.a and headers file), I want to bind this library to Xamarin.iOS

I found the binding steps mention on Xamarin site [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/) and in this walkthrough they use the source code of library. But I have only `.a` file and headers file.

Is it possible to bind the static library without the source code.

Comment: The guide just uses the sources to build the `.a` file. The rest is done using the headers and the binary. Objective sharpie needs only the headers.

Comment: If you read that link they start with the source to build the library, then bind said library.  So that link tells you all you need to know, you just need to start halfway through.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the source code to bind with Objective Sharpie.  All you need is the `.a` library and the headers.

Here's an example:

```
sharpie bind -output Binding -sdk iphoneos8.1 \
-scope build/Headers build/Headers/SomeHeader.h \
-c -Ibuild/Headers -arch arm64
```

Objective Sharpie just output two files: `Binding/ApiDefinitions.cs` and `Binding/StructsAndEnums.cs`.

Then you tweak the bindings as needed and run again.

Once the tweaks are complete, these two files can now be added to a binding project in Xamarin Studio or be passed directly to the `touch` (iOS) or `mac` (MacOS X) tools to produce the final binding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible via Objective Sharpie(https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/)

Objective Sharpie uses `clang` to parse header files which generates quality API definitions. For the things Objective Sharpie cannot parse/generate, you'll need to normalize yourself. These generated files are known as the `ApiDefinition.cs` and the `StructsAndEnums.cs`.

To accomplish this, you can use the `sharpie bind` command.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/#Using_Objective_Sharpie

Once you have generated the respective template/scaffolding, you can then pass these items into the `bmac`/`btouch` binding tooling which will generate the binding for your platform (Mac/iOS respectfully).

If you're still running into trouble, there's an advanced example here that should also help:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/advanced/